# How Multiple inheritance is supported in Interface without constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

With out constructor chaining there is no possible of inheritance occurs then how inheritance  occurs in interface and multiple inheritance is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Between a class and an interface there is no inheritance, but *implementation* relationship. Since a class that implements multiple interfaces is actually not inheriting anything them, I don't see any problem. The implementor class doesn't have to invoke constructors because the interface is only a kind of *contract*: the implementor classes must provide the interface methods.

Comment: Classes *can* now inherit things from interfaces, specifically default methods.

Comment: Classes inherit everything except static methods from the interfaces they inherit, and always have. This answer is therefore plain wrong. From the JLS: "A class C _inherits_ from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces all `abstract` and default (§9.4) methods `m` for which all of the following are true: ..." (Emphasis original)

Answer (score 0):

You're starting with a false premise:

> With out constructor chaining there is no possible of inheritance...

Constructor chaining isn't required for there to be inheritance.

Interfaces have no per-instance state, and no constructors (the fact they don't have per-instance state is essential to their not having constructors). However, they can include

- abstract methods (e.g., without implementations), which the class inherits and must either implement or, if it's an abstract class, declare `abstract`
- `default` methods with implementations that are inherited by the implementing class unless the class defines its own implementation

Re `default` methods, say you have:

```
interface TheInterface {
    default void answer() {
        System.out.println("42");
    }
}
class TheClass implements TheInterface {
}
```

Then you have:

```
TheClass c = new TheClass();
c.answer(); // Outputs "42"
```

`TheClass` inherits from `TheInterface`, both from a type perspective (an instance of `TheClass` "is a" `TheInterface`) and an implementation perspective (`TheClass` inherits the implementation of `answer` from `TheInterface`). But there is no constructor chaining, because interfaces do not have constructors, because they do not have per-instance state.

---

You might be tempted to think that there's a no-args constructor that `TheClass` calls, but we can see from the bytecode that `TheClass`'s constructor chains to `Object`, not `TheInterface`:

`javap -c TheClass`:

```
class TheClass implements TheInterface {
  TheClass();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."":()V
       4: return
}
```

Comment: Classes also inherit the abstract methods from their superinterfaces.

Comment: @LewBloch: What do you mean, the signature? I covered that "...from a type perspective." Obviously not the implementation, as there isn't one, by definition. I can clarify that, sure.

Comment: I'm simply pointing out that the JLS explicitly says that classes inherit abstract and default methods from their superinterfaces. I mean exactly what the JLS means.